# Avahi mDNS blocked in queue

Tags: ubuntu, networking, avahi, mdns

Im running avahi-daemon 0.8 on a arm64 embedded device (Ubuntu 20.04.6). If I acces the device in browser with IP directly in loads in 2ms maximum, but if use the host-name created by me with '.local' domain it stays a lot in in blocked part and only after a certain time. Here is a screenshoot with timings in firefox, from windows
[image: timing from developer console]

Also, my avahi-daemon.conf file:

```
[server]
host-name=name
domain-name=local
#browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=no
#allow-interfaces=lo.IPv4, lan1.IPv4
#deny-interfaces=eth1
#check-response-ttl=no
#use-iff-running=no
#enable-dbus=yes
#disallow-other-stacks=no
allow-point-to-point=yes
#cache-entries-max=4096
#clients-max=4096
#objects-per-client-max=1024
#entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=no

[publish]
#disable-publishing=yes
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
#publish-addresses=yes
#publish-hinfo=no
#publish-workstation=no
#publish-domain=no
#publish-dns-servers=
#publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
#publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
#enable-reflector=no
#reflect-ipv=no
#reflect-filters=_airplay._tcp.local,_raop._tcp.local

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
#rlimit-core=0
#rlimit-data=8388608
#rlimit-fsize=0
#rlimit-nofile=768
#rlimit-stack=8388608
#rlimit-nproc=3
```

I mean `.local` as a mDNS domain. Here is also the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` context:

```
passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mymachines dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Do you  mean `.local` as a mDNS domain, or have you set up a conflicting `hostname.local` domain name in regular DNS? What does the `hosts:` line in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contain? If `resolve` is included, please show your `resolvectl status` output too. Please add this information by **editing your original post.**